# How to calculate working day in Date Dimension

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, dimensions

In Date dimension, I want to calculate WorkingDaysToDate attribute, which should indicate total  number of working days till today from the start of the month, say for example

Today is 27th Sept (Friday), then

WorkingDaysToDate is Total Number of working date till today in a month subtract any Weekends and Public holidays

And result should be:

27th Sept (Friday): 20 working days,
28th Sept (Saturday): 20, 
29th sept (Sun): 20 working days,
30th Sept (Mon) then there should be 21 working days
and so on

I am getting correct result, for a current day using below code but I want to calculate for all the dates in date dimension :

```
WITH CTE AS 
(   
select * from dbo.Date_Dimension
where DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE()) = CalendarMonthNumber
AND DATEPART(year,getdate()) = CalendarYearNumber
AND Fulldate between DATEADD(Month,DateDiff(Month,0,Getdate()),0)  
AND convert (Date, GETDATE()) 
AND HolidayFlag = 0
AND WeekDayFlag = 1     )


Select COUNT (*) AS WorkingDayToDate from CTE
```

And as mentioned, this will give me result only for the current date, but I want to calculate and store for all the dates in Date dimension

Can someone please help

Please see below create table code and sample insert code to populate date dimension for faster execution :

To Create Date_dimension Table, use below code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Date_Dimension](
[DateSK] [int] NOT NULL,
[FullDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Day] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[DaySuffix] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
[DayOfWeek] [varchar](9) NOT NULL,
[DayOfWeekNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
[DayOfWeekInMonth] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[DayOfYearNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
[RelativeDays] [int] NOT NULL,
[WeekOfYearNumber] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[WeekOfMonthNumber] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[RelativeWeeks] [int] NOT NULL,
[CalendarMonthNumber] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[CalendarMonthName] [varchar](9) NOT NULL,
[RelativeMonths] [int] NOT NULL,
[CalendarQuarterNumber]     [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[CalendarQuarterName]     [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
[RelativeQuarters]     [int] NOT NULL,
[CalendarYearNumber]     [int] NOT NULL,
[RelativeYears]     [int] NOT NULL,
[StandardDate]     [varchar](10) NULL,
[WeekDayFlag]     [bit] NOT NULL,
[HolidayFlag]     [bit] NOT NULL,
[OpenFlag]     [bit] NOT NULL,
[FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag]     [bit] NOT NULL,
[LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag]     [bit] NOT NULL,
[HolidayText]     [varchar](50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT     [PK_DimDate] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[DateSK] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON     [PRIMARY]
) ON     [PRIMARY]

GO
```

And to populate sample data, you can use below code:

```
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130901,'2013-09-01 00:00:00.000',1,'1st','Sunday',1,1,244,-26,36,1,-3,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/01/2013',0,0,0,1,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130902,'2013-09-02 00:00:00.000',2,'2nd','Monday',2,1,245,-25,36,1,-3,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/02/2013',1,0,1,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130903,'2013-09-03 00:00:00.000',3,'3rd','Tuesday',3,1,246,-24,36,1,-3,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/03/2013',1,0,1,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130904,'2013-09-04 00:00:00.000',4,'4th','Wednesday',4,1,247,-23,36,1,-3,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/04/2013',1,0,1,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130905,'2013-09-05 00:00:00.000',5,'5th','Thursday',5,1,248,-22,36,1,-3,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/05/2013',1,0,1,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130906,'2013-09-06 00:00:00.000',6,'6th','Friday',6,1,249,-21,36,1,-3,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/06/2013',1,0,1,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130907,'2013-09-07 00:00:00.000',7,'7th','Saturday',7,1,250,-20,36,1,-3,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/07/2013',0,0,1,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130908,'2013-09-08 00:00:00.000',8,'8th','Sunday',1,2,251,-19,37,2,-2,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/08/2013',0,0,0,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130909,'2013-09-09 00:00:00.000',9,'9th','Monday',2,2,252,-18,37,2,-2,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/09/2013',1,0,1,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130910,'2013-09-10 00:00:00.000',10,'10th','Tuesday',3,2,253,-17,37,2,-2,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/10/2013',1,0,1,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130911,'2013-09-11 00:00:00.000',11,'11th','Wednesday',4,2,254,-16,37,2,-2,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/11/2013',1,0,1,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130912,'2013-09-12 00:00:00.000',12,'12th','Thursday',5,2,255,-15,37,2,-2,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/12/2013',1,0,1,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130913,'2013-09-13 00:00:00.000',13,'13th','Friday',6,2,256,-14,37,2,-2,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/13/2013',1,0,1,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130914,'2013-09-14 00:00:00.000',14,'14th','Saturday',7,2,257,-13,37,2,-2,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/14/2013',0,0,1,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130915,'2013-09-15 00:00:00.000',15,'15th','Sunday',1,3,258,-12,38,3,-1,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/15/2013',0,0,0,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130916,'2013-09-16 00:00:00.000',16,'16th','Monday',2,3,259,-11,38,3,-1,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/16/2013',1,0,1,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130917,'2013-09-17 00:00:00.000',17,'17th','Tuesday',3,3,260,-10,38,3,-1,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/17/2013',1,0,1,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130918,'2013-09-18 00:00:00.000',18,'18th','Wednesday',4,3,261,-9,38,3,-1,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/18/2013',1,0,1,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130919,'2013-09-19 00:00:00.000',19,'19th','Thursday',5,3,262,-8,38,3,-1,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/19/2013',1,0,1,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130920,'2013-09-20 00:00:00.000',20,'20th','Friday',6,3,263,-7,38,3,-1,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/20/2013',1,0,1,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130921,'2013-09-21 00:00:00.000',21,'21st','Saturday',7,3,264,-6,38,3,-1,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/21/2013',0,0,1,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130922,'2013-09-22 00:00:00.000',22,'22nd','Sunday',1,4,265,-5,39,4,0,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/22/2013',0,0,0,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130923,'2013-09-23 00:00:00.000',23,'23rd','Monday',2,4,266,-4,39,4,0,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/23/2013',1,0,1,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130924,'2013-09-24 00:00:00.000',24,'24th','Tuesday',3,4,267,-3,39,4,0,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/24/2013',1,0,1,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130925,'2013-09-25 00:00:00.000',25,'25th','Wednesday',4,4,268,-2,39,4,0,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/25/2013',1,0,1,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130926,'2013-09-26 00:00:00.000',26,'26th','Thursday',5,4,269,-1,39,4,0,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/26/2013',1,0,1,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130927,'2013-09-27 00:00:00.000',27,'27th','Friday',6,4,270,0,39,4,0,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/27/2013',1,0,1,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130928,'2013-09-28 00:00:00.000',28,'28th','Saturday',7,4,271,1,39,4,0,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/28/2013',0,0,1,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130929,'2013-09-29 00:00:00.000',29,'29th','Sunday',1,5,272,2,40,5,1,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/29/2013',0,0,0,0,0,NULL)
INSERT INTO Date_dimension(DateSK,FullDate,Day,DaySuffix,DayOfWeek,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekInMonth,DayOfYearNumber,RelativeDays,WeekOfYearNumber,WeekOfMonthNumber,RelativeWeeks,CalendarMonthNumber,CalendarMonthName,RelativeMonths,CalendarQuarterNumber,CalendarQuarterName,RelativeQuarters,CalendarYearNumber,RelativeYears,StandardDate,WeekDayFlag,HolidayFlag,OpenFlag,FirstDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,LastDayOfCalendarMonthFlag,HolidayText) VALUES (20130930,'2013-09-30 00:00:00.000',30,'30th','Monday',2,5,273,3,40,5,1,9,'September',0,3,'Third',0,2013,0,'09/30/2013',1,0,1,0,1,NULL)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A window function with an [OVER() clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) can make quick work of your requirement.  Note, this will only work in SQL 2012 and above, ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING is new to 2012.

The key to this is the ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING in conjunction with the PARTITION BY clause.  This says, group by year and month and then for that year-month combination sum up the work days based on my case statement criteria.

**SQL Server 2012 Optimization**

```
select 
  fulldate,
  sum(case 
        when holidayFlag = 0 and weekdayFlag = 1 then 1 
        else 0 
      end) over(partition by year(fulldate), month(fulldate)
                order by fulldate 
                ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
from date_dimension
```

[SQL Fiddle for 2012 Version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/83220/1/0).

**SQL Server 2008**

```
 -- This will be slower than 2012 version
select 
   d1.fulldate,
   (select 
    sum(case 
          when d2.holidayFlag = 0 and d2.weekdayFlag = 1 then 1 
          else 0 
        end)
    from date_dimension d2
    where d1.fulldate >= d2.fulldate
    and year(d1.fulldate) = year(d2.fulldate)
    and month(d1.fulldate) = month(d2.fulldate)) x
from date_dimension d1
group by d1.fulldate
```

[SQL Fiddle for 2008 Version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83220/16/0)

Fastest way to do this in 2008 is a cursor see [Calculate a Running Total in SqlServer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/861073/2286801). However, for your requirement this should work fine.

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt response, but we are still using SQL 2008. What could be possible solution for SQL 2008 version